# kW Rating of emergency generator for sump pump

Tags: power, current

I have a 1/2HP [sump pump](http://www.sumppumpsdirect.com/Zoeller-M267-Sewage-Pump/p3754.html) rated at 11 Amps running and 43 Amps starting. I would like to buy an emergency portable generator to power it. I know that for 11 Amps I'd need at least 11 x 110 = 1210 Watts, and for 43 Amps = 4730 Watt. Generators also have running/starting watt rating.

**So what is my minimum required rating running/starting Amps if I need a generator to power ONLY this pump?**

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question: you need a generator with a minimum running current of 11 amperes and a minimum starting current of 43 amperes.  To be safe, I would suggest getting a generator with minimum running/starting ratings of 15/50 amperes.

Comment: Amount of flywheel on generator MAY affect capability.  If pump starts rapidly motor inertia MAY be enough to supply startup energy.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have answered your own question: you need a generator with a minimum running current of 11 amperes and a minimum starting current of 43 amperes.  To be safe, I would suggest getting a generator with minimum running/starting ratings of 15/50 amperes. Assuming a 120 volt system, as implied in your question, the corresponding wattage requirements are 1800/6000.